# Get greatest common value in a column across tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables (say A, B, C and D) all with the column 'date'. I need to find the greatest common date value across all four tables. That is, the greatest value of date that exists in all four tables. How can I do this?

For now, I'm making do with finding the MIN of the MAX date values of all four tables, but this fails in the cases where the MIN exists in one table but not in the second.

Here is an example to make things clearer :

```
A.date
------
2015-03-31
2015-03-30
2015-03-29
2015-03-27

B.date
------
2015-03-30
2015-03-29
2015-03-28
2015-03-27

C.date
------
2015-03-29
2015-03-27
2015-03-26
2015-03-25

D.date
------
2015-03-28
2015-03-27
2015-03-26
2015-03-25
```

What I was doing to find the highest common date was :

```
SELECT MIN(max_date) FROM (
SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM A
UNION
SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM B
UNION
SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM C
UNION
SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM D
) T;
```

This gives me 2015-03-28, but then I realized that some tables might not have this date at all. The date I actually want to get is 2015-03-27.

Comment: Please show the sql that you say is failing as well as example and expected data.

Comment: If you just want the max date, could you not select each date from each table, union them together and get the max?

Comment: @paqogomez . . . Because the OP does not want the maximum date.  The OP wants the maximum date that appears in *all four* tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select date
from (select date, 'a' as which from a union all
      select date, 'b' as which from b union all
      select date, 'c' as which from c union all
      select date, 'd' as which from d
     ) x
group by date
having count(distinct which) = 4
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

The following version might perform a bit better, especially if you have an index on `date` in each table:

```
select date
from (select distinct date, 'a' as which from a union all
      select distinct date, 'b' as which from b union all
      select distinct date, 'c' as which from c union all
      select distinct date, 'd' as which from d
     ) x
group by date
having count(*) = 4
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an *intersection* of all date values across the 4 separate tables. Then, select the `MAX` of these values:

```
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM A
WHERE date IN (
  SELECT date 
  FROM B
  WHERE date IN (
     SELECT date
     FROM C
     WHERE date IN (
        SELECT date
        FROM D)))
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d8c2/2)